# Wildfly - Configuração de acesso externo

Tags: jboss, wildfly

Estou fazendo a configuração para liberar acesso as portas do Wildfly e encontrei essas duas formas. Não encontrei qual a diferença entre as duas, se é que existe.

Qual é a diferença entre as duas configurações:

```
<any-address/>
```

e

```
<inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:0.0.0.0}"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A interface public é utilizado por todas comunicações de rede relacionadas as aplicações.

A interface management é utilizada por todos os componentes e serviços que são exigidos pela camada de gerenciamento do servidor.

fonte:

[different-ip-address-multihomed](http://blog.arungupta.me/bind-wildfly-different-ip-address-multihomed/)

[Interfaces and ports](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Interfaces+and+ports)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Minha dúvida é sobre as tagas <any-address> e <inet-address>. Após ver sua resposta percebi que realmente não soube me expressar.